# Keep the data from a user input from a 'for loop'

Tags: c#, loops

This is not the full code. I just don't know how to store multiple data the user inputs in a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < INum; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0} Number: ", i);
    int Vnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int a, b = 0, c = 0;

    b = Vnum / 2;
    for (a = 2; a <= b; a++)
    {
        if (Vnum % a == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Composite");
            int Cnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//sad attempt in storing multiple data.
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (c == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prime");
        int Pnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//sad attempt in storing multiple data.
    }
```

Comment: You could use a `List<ìnt>` to store multiple integer values.

Comment: I tried to attempt that. Is there any syntax or example I can follow? I can't find any on the internet that I can understand. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/collections/lists/

Comment: Create a variable `var list = new List<int>()` and then assign each value using `list.Add(Cnum)`.

Comment: `var Cnum = new ArrayList();
                        Cnum.Add(Vnum);
                        c = 1;
                        break;//should I put this here?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<int>` to store multiple data. I changed your code to store data in list as follow:

```
    List<int> Vnum = new List<int>();

    List<int> Cnum = new List<int>();

    List<int> Pnum = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < INum; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} Number: ", i);
        Vnum.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

        int a, b = 0, c = 0;

        b = Vnum[Vnum.Count - 1] / 2;
        for (a = 2; a <= b; a++)
        {
            if (Vnum[Vnum.Count - 1] % a == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Composite");
                Cnum.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                c = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (c == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Prime");
            Pnum.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
    }
```